# Override clone() for DataColumn

Tags: c#, datacolumn

I have a customized CustomDataColumn which derives from System.Data.DataColumn to extend the DataColumn with a few properties.

```
public class CustomDataColumn : DataColumn
```

I put this CustomDataColumn in a DataTable with dtab.Columns.Add(). To support DataTable.Clone() I put an empty constructor in my CustomDataColumn - Class but the additional properties are not cloned. So I tried to override the clone methode which did not works (no methode to override error which is strange because it can clone the standard fields of DataColumn). Next I tried to implement the IClonable - Interface but my own clone methode is not called. Do I have to override the DataTable clone methode as well to call my own DataColumn clone methode? Any suggestions?